# Is it possible to use the WinRT from a non-metro application?

Tags: windows-8, desktop-application, windows-runtime

Demos and articles I see online talk about Windows Runtime with Metro-style apps. Is it possible to use APIs with non-metro applications?

Comment: I wonder why you would want to?

Comment: If Operating System is providing Runtime which you can use for programming then why only available for metro style apps? I mean if they are just set of APIs (based on COM) then it should be possible to use them in desktop apps as well. bdw, I found a blog which explains this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just found a way on Jeffrey Richter's [blog](http://www.wintellect.com/cs/blogs/jeffreyr/archive/2011/09/20/using-the-windows-runtime-from-a-non-metro-application.aspx), Cool.

Answer (score 1):

[Real Native WinRT Development -](http://www.interact-sw.co.uk/iangblog/2011/09/16/real-native-winrt)